Azure blob batch delete command throws error
I am using below azure command
az storage blob delete-batch --account-name $account --source $container --pattern 'Test1/*'  --connection-string $connectionString

I am receiving an error as below
az storage blob delete-batch --account-name $account --source $contai ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (WARNING: Comman...s/CLI_refstatus:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Any idea what could be the error?

Try adding the --debug flag to the end of your command and post the complete error message here: az storage blob delete-batch ....... --debug


az storage blob delete-batch --account-name $account --source $container ...
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (WARNING: Comman...s/CLI_refstatus:String) [], RemoteException

Initially, I also got the same error in my environment.

The above error occurs mostly when you are passing wrong values or incorrect parameters.
I agree with Rui Jarimba's comment, --debug flag will give you the full error.
Command:
$account="venkat123"
$container="sample"
$connectionString="xxx"
az storage blob delete-batch --account-name $account --source $container --pattern 'folder1/*'  --connection-string $connectionString --debug

Error:
RequestId:2442f000-901e-0043-5adf-b38ca2000000
Time:2024-06-01T04:53:21.3126230Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 's8LOxxxxx+jTDnlwM9scOaGs=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used the following 
string to sign: 'GET
x-ms-client-request-id:de6720bf-1fd2-11ef-bf06-a0291972d157
x-ms-date:Sat, 01 Jun 2024 04:53:20 GMT
x-ms-version:2022-11-02
/venkat123/sample
comp:list
prefix:folder1/
restype:container'.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>
ERROR: cli.azure.cli.core.azclierror: 
Authentication failure. This may be caused by either an invalid account key, connection string, or sas token value provided for your storage account.

In my environment, I passed the wrong connection String. After passing the correct connectionString, it worked successfully.
Command and Output:
PS C:\Users\xxx> $account="venkat123"
$container="sample"
$connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=venkat123;AccountKey=7xxxxxQYCm+AStmeIVYA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
az storage blob delete-batch --account-name $account --source $container --pattern 'folder1/*'  --connection-string $connectionString 

PS C:\Users\xxx> 


Reference:
az storage blob | Microsoft Learn
